# DOM: How to set element width based on iterator value and call a function on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I have this issue: I used [this](http://designshack.net/articles/css/verticalaccordionav/) tutorial to create this really nice compact nav menu, but it has an issue in that you've got to hardcode the height. I wanna, as an exercise in JS, to try and bypass that by setting the height in JS based on the iterator value that find the list in the element and goes through all the list elements in the, well... list and then I assign the height based on that iterator (with every list element having 15px of space).

Here is my code:

```
/* Input the current nav menu element id here. Should be unordered. */
function handleListById(idname) {
    var object = document.getElementById(idname);
    var list = object.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0, length = list.length; i < length; i++ ) {
        object.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.height = 15*i + "px";
    }
}
```

And then I try to fire that off with

```
<div class="menu-item" id="first" onmouseover="handleListById('first')">
```

But it doesn't work. I suspect It has to do with the fact that in CSS I specify the changed height with `:hover`; whereas here it is not present at all. But then how do I proceed? Do I have to use jQuery?

Please don't pay attention to the unnecessary variables and stuff, it's to help myself learn.

Comment: UPDATE: corrected some stupid mistakes in the code. Still the issue persists: the item does not change height when I hover over it.

Comment: Maybe you could try add single quote to onmouseover `onmouseover="handleListById('first')"`. Also change `document.getElementById("idname");` to `document.getElementById(idname);`?

Comment: A live demo (e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It's very late and I have been working since 8am, my head barely works anymore. I made lots of stupid mistakes that I now corrected. Not sure why Stack Overflow didn't show my corrections, it only showed you pointing them out after I made the edits, which is strange. In any case, I fixed it, but it still doesn't work. It finds only 2 li elements instead of 3 and worst of all: it doesn't animate.
I set up a jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2QGu/
And an example of how it works with pure CSS (how I want it to look) here: http://jsfiddle.net/bYzJ2/
Soz for stupid mistakes

Comment: The second jsfiddle link is broken too ffs... Here is the proper one: http://jsfiddle.net/bYzJ2/3/

Also wanna point out how with the script it covers the entire list with links in white. It does extend the element's width, but it's just extra whitespace, no list elements show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of issues relates to your code.

1. Why use a for loop if you only want to times `i` when the value will becomes `15 * 2` any way?
2. `onmouseover="handleListById(first)"` should have single quote around `first` like this `onmouseover="handleListById('first')"`
3. When using `style.height` you have to append `"px"` at the end.
4. You shouldn't get `ul` element which you only have 1, instead you should get `li`.
5. `document.getElementById("idname")` should be `document.getElementById(idname)` without double quote.
6. You shouldn't set the height of `object`, instead you should set the height of `ul` within the `div`.

Try this

```
function handleListById(idname) {
    var object = document.getElementById(idname);
    var list   = object.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    var items  = object.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var height = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
        height += items[i].clientHeight
    }
    list[0].style.height = height + "px";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-item" id="first" onmouseover="handleListById('first')">
```

And don't forget to reset the height on mouseout

Comment: Yeah I did this, and it works but:
It just drops down a white bar (list items don't show).
Animation is gone.
It only somehow finds 2 li items, when I have 3.

Comment: Ok It's really strange. I typed this in myself and it worked :O Thanks a lot, but can please explain what is this .clientHeight thing?

Comment: @Megakoresh when you trying to get the height of an element. You could not use `style.height` because it only get the value defined in element's inline style. No inline style no value. `clientHeight` get the height of the element plus padding minus scroll bar (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight).

Comment: So because I specified the default height to 0 in CSS for this, the `style.height` didn't work? This is a very useful tip, it helped me a lot in a bunch of other situations, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify 'px' when building the height dynamically.

```
object.style.height = (15*1) + 'px';
```

You also have an issue on your `onmouseover` attribute where you're passing in an undefined variable instead of a string. Use `handleListById('first')` as the answer above mine specifies

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu-item" id="first" onmouseover="handleListById('first');">
```

instead of `handleListById(first)

Also,  use `object.style.height = (15*i) + 'px';`